# How to fix asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have this custom authorization when accessing a controller but I keep getting the following the above error: Can anyone help me to identify the issue in my code?

```
//Controller
[GlobalDataAuthorization]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}

// Custom Authorization
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class GlobalDataAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public  async override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var authorizationBuilder = new AuthorizationBuilder();
        bool hasAccess = await authorizationBuilder.GetUserAccess();
        if (!hasAccess)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home");
        }    
    }

}
```

Builder class to check user access:

```
public interface IAuthorizationBuilder
{
    Task<bool> GetUserAccess();
}

public class AuthorizationBuilder : IAuthorizationBuilder
{
    public async Task<bool> GetUserAccess()
    {

        var authConfigsResponse = await GetAuthConfigurationsAsync(); //http request
        var allSupportedRoles =  SetUpAllSupportedRoles(authConfigsResponse);
        var supportedRoles = SetUpSupportedRoles(allSupportedRoles);
        var result = await CheckClaimsAsync(supportedRoles, allSupportedRoles);//http request
        return result;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `async override void OnAuthorization` is not valid, you cannot just take a synchronous method and make it asynchronous - the caller will have no way to wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET (pre-Core) MVC does not support asynchronous filters. ASP.NET Core MVC does support asynchronous filters.

Assuming you're not ready to move to Core yet (which is the eventually-necessary solution), you'll need to do some kind of sync-over-async antipattern. I have a [few hacks in an article I wrote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) that you could use.

For example, the blocking threadpool hack works for most code, especially in an ASP.NET setting:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  var authorizationBuilder = new AuthorizationBuilder();
  bool hasAccess = Task.Run(() => authorizationBuilder.GetUserAccess()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  if (!hasAccess)
  {
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home");
  }    
}
```